# How to detect number in string in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I try to parse file and the need to detect number for every column in the tags. I need to detect:

1. If there is a number
2. If the number is 1-3 digits.
3. If there is a single dot at the begin, end or a separated dot (I can do the last two detections of dot with string substitution but detection of number I don't know).

I already have the for loop that extracts the data in tags:

```
for %%Z in (hide_2.htm) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 delims=<>" %%A on ('grep -B 1411 -E "</table>" %%Z ^| grep -E ^"^(display^|^^\d\d{1,3}^|country^|^<td^>HTTP^|rightborder^).*$^" ') do (
        echo A:%%A + %%B + %%C + %%D + %%E + %%F + %%G + %%H + %%I + %%J + %%K + %%L
        pause
    )
)
```

The input is:
A:          + td + span + span + **41** + /span + span style="display: none;" + **111**
+ /span + div +  +
A: style="display: none;" + **190** + /div + span class="" style="" +**.** + /span + span + **197** + /span + span +  +
A: style="display: none;" + **24** + /span + span + /span + **.** + span style="display:
  +  +  +  +  +
A:inline;" + **132** + /span + span style="display: none;" + **39** + /span + **.** + span
+  +  +  +
A:style="display: inline;" + 186 + /span + /span + /td +         +  +  +  +  +
+
A:          + td rel="rw" + span class="country" + img  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
A:              + td + HTTPS + /td +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +

The source data are taken from [here](http://codepaste.net/1kj4xb).

**Edit:**
The best would be to keep two variables. 1st variable to keep the number, and the second variable to keep the dot or a flag if the dot exists.

**Edit2:**
The input values can be for example: 120,132,186,24,111,41,., or .120,.132,.186,.24,.111,.41 ... The values can be in any of the columns.

**Edit3:**
The number is always on the end of column. And the dot can be on begin but must not be in the result of the number variable.

Comment: Complicated string parsing in batch scripts could be painful. Why not use Sed or AWK for this purpose?

Comment: I have no problem with parsing, but with detection of number. If I would want to make a loop for string to detect number in the way of if !digit!==1 () if !digit!==2 () if !digit!==3 () and so on, how can I parse the string into separate characters? I could use For /L loop if I would know how to measure length of the string.

Comment: You're already extracting one word at a time, so what you basically need is code to detect if the word (variable) is a number, and how many digits it contains. Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly. But it is also possible, that there can be a dot. Because the numbers are separated parts of IP address.

Comment: Can you please fix the input?

Comment: What do you mean "to fix input"? The number can be in one of the columns, but I don't know if the dot is part of the number... What is the procedure to find out if the variable is number? Maybe I could to change it to fix input?

Comment: The "+" is only part of the debugging procedure. See: `echo A:%%A + %%B +` and so on ... The plus is as for separator/delimiter between the columns to be better visible. Yes, spans can be in one of the columns. That's why I need to detect if the value is number or whatever else

Comment: I found interesting code here, maybe it could help? I did some test, it needs to repair, but see my code in question

Comment: If only says if a number (or a dot) exists. But if it's true, it doesn't say where.

Comment: The number is always on the end of column. I need not to know where the number is (but I know that it is on the end of column), but I need the number... My try does not work because echo will always return errorlevel 0 as success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "$=0" &if defined $ if !$! equ +!$! echo. isNumber: '!$!'
set "$=NaN" &if defined $ if !$! equ +!$! echo. isNumber: '!$!'

if "%VAR%" neq "" if %VAR% equ +%VAR% echo. %VAR% is a number.
```

Solution by Ed Dyreen, thanks!

Comment: Nice idea, but if will fail if number starts with 0 and contains 8 or 9 digit because IF will parse it as octal. That can be fixed by prefixing with 1. But will also fail if number is negative. Cannot fix the negative problem.

Comment: @dbenham I don't think negative numbers are involved, the OP says they are the fields of an IP address.

Comment: @EitanT - Yea, the question wasn't clear, but the comment does say IP address. However, others referencing this question and answer from a more general perspective should be aware of the limitation(s).

Comment: @dbenham, what do you think about assigning `set /A CMP=+VAR`, then using `%CMP%` for the comparison rather than `+%VAR%`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest and most flexible method is to use the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

```cmd
@echo off
set "_VALUE=%~1" & rem // (take value from first command line argument)

cmd /V /C echo(!_VALUE!| > nul findstr /R /X ^
    /C:"00*" /C:"[-+]00*" ^
    /C:"[123456789][0123456789]*" ^
    /C:"[-+][123456789][0123456789]*" ^
    && echo The value "%_VALUE%" is numeric.
```

You can specify multiple search strings one of which must match for the value to be considered as numeric.

The extra `cmd` instance is intended to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (due to `/V`), which is needed to be able to `echo` every arbitrary string even with unbalanced quotation marks and special characters, like `^`, `&`, for instance. If such cannot occur, you may replace the portion `cmd /V /C echo(!_VALUE!` by `echo(%_VALUE%`.